# ListView with InsertItemTemplate doesnt work

Tags: asp.net

```
 <asp:ListView ID="lvWallPosts" runat="server" 
        onitemcommand="lvWallPosts_ItemCommand" InsertItemPosition="LastItem">
    <LayoutTemplate>
                <table cellpadding="2" runat="server" id="tblWallPosts" 
                    style="width:460px">
                  <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder">
                  </tr>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtMessage" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>          
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>

                 <tr id="Tr2" style="height:72px" runat="server">
                   <td valign="top" class="EmployeeInfo">
                   <p>
                     <div class="wallmark"><asp:Image ID="imgFile" runat="server" CssClass="friendsImage" ImageUrl='<%# "HttpImageHandler.jpg?username=" +  DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ByUsername").ToString() %>' />
                     <asp:Label ID="lblFrom" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ByUsername") %>' Font-Size="0.9em" Font-Underline="false" /><br />
                     <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Message") %>' Font-Size="0.9em" Font-Underline="false"/></div>
                     <asp:LinkButton CssClass="shareText" runat="server" ID="lblComment" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' CommandName="Insert" Font-Size="0.9em" Font-Underline="false">Comment</asp:LinkButton>
                     <asp:LinkButton CssClass="shareText" runat="server" ID="lbShare" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' CommandName="Share" Font-Size="0.9em" Font-Underline="false">Share</asp:LinkButton>   
                   </td>
                 </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:ListView>
```

I cant see the txtMessage control when I click on linkbutton comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try setting the linkbutton's commandname to "InitInsert" instead of "Insert"